# No endpoint mapping found for [SaajSoapMessage , exception during SOAP WS execution

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, endpoint

I'm a newbie to SOAP web service development using String.

I had followed below process to create a Soap Web service using Spring
https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/

*Error message :*
2020-04-27 20:53:31.979  WARN 4860 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.ws.server.EndpointNotFound           :
 **No endpoint mapping found for [SaajSoapMessage** {http://opnt.com.si/opnt/OnGSSNorBodGateway/}FeasibilityCheck]

**Endpoint class:**

@Endpoint
public class NltProcessEndpoint{

```
private static final String NAMESPACE1 = "http://opnt.com.si/opnt/OnGSSNorBodGateway";

@Autowired
private NltService service;
@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE1, localPart = "FeasibilityCheck")
@ResponsePayload
public FeasibilityCheckResponse getResponseMessage(@RequestPayload FeasibilityCheckRequest request) {
    FeasibilityCheckResponse feasibilityResponse = new FeasibilityCheckResponse();
    feasibilityResponse = service.checkFeasibility(request);
    return feasibilityResponse;
}
```

}

I can share my code if required.

Comment: You should include the relevant part(s) of the code you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Namespace of XSD and endpoint class as not matching due to which the error came.

In ENDPOINT class
NAMESPACE1 = "http://opnt.com.si/opnt/OnGSSNorBodGateway"

In XSD 
targetNamespace = "http://opnt.com.si/opnt/OnGSSNorBodGateway/"